# I can't load the static files(javascript or css) in my Slim framework application

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, slim

I have developed the rest api services using Slim framework. Now i have to create the web views to make a dashboard. I have installed twig view and it working fine. But I can't load the css and javascript file from the view page. The project tree is in below structure

```
/pani 
 /public
    index.php // public index to enter the appliaction
   .htaccess
 /repository
 /application
   /routes
     DB.php  // application database connection
     LoginRegistration.php  //login form routing
   /views
     /css   // folder containing more subfolder with css and js files
     home.php // view page for logi
/vendor
   composer.json
   composer.lock
```

My .htaccess file code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

when I am trying to run the application I got the following errors

[image: Error files when running the page]

I am stuck with the problem. I cant add any javascript or other css files from the view. Please suggest me way. If this structure looks complex show me with a easy structure of the application. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a closing curly brace after REQUEST_FILENAME, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: First of all thanks @BrianGottier for your reply. That solved one part. The ERR_ABORTED message is removed but still i am getting 404 error.

Comment: I got my issue. The pathway was wrong. Now everything is perfect. Thank you so so much Brian.